# Touchpad not working after suspend Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, touchpad, xinput

My mousepad is not working after suspend on a Lenovo E460. It used to work perfectly but after this it **no longer even appears in xinput**. I have tried to plug in a mouse and that works fine.

Edit: Restarting etc. does not make it work again, it is completely gone as of after the suspend.

Comment: Known bug with intel video driver: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1573454

Comment: This is not the same bug as I stated, Their issue is with the pointer not being visible while mine is the entire touchpad is not being recognized. The workarounds for that bug does not work for me.

Comment: Did you suspend to RAM or suspend to disk (= hibernate)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editing the grub file from,

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

to,

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="i8042.reset i8042.nomux i8042.nopnp i8042.noloop"

then updating grub solved the problem.

Comment: What does this fix do? I put it in `/etc/default/grub` and it fixed it for Fujitsu Lifebook T725, but I don't understand why it works now. Will it have any side effects?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and after some research, I found this solution which worked for me:

1) Open terminal
    <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2) type in terminal
    `sudo depmod -a`
3) then enter your password
4) restart your pc [ you can use `init 0` to shutdown, as mouse not working]

After the restart, your touchpad will work normally.